# How to convert from dot notation to bracket notation in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I would like to format JavaScript code from `object.property` to `object['property']`. Is there an extension to do this, or a built-in way that I'm missing?

Comment: Is there a reason for that? "... or a built-in way that I'm missing" Regex replace?

Comment: To caveat off of Thomas suggestion, you can even go one step further and assign a keyboard shortcut to automatically search and trigger a find for a specific regex, but if you looking for a ‘command palette’ route, there is no native support no, but there could be an extension I just personally don’t know of any, but that would make your question off topic anyways for recommendations.

Comment: @Thomas taking existing code and making it adhere to a new style guide. And other reasons (better minification with bracket notation, etc.). Using regex will be tricky since lots of the code has both extended properties and own properties (e.g., length).

Answer (score -1):

**I think there no need to any `extension` you can it in simple way like this ..**

**Also you can access it in both way ..**

```js
var obj = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
};

obj.key3 = "value3";

console.log("Added by dot notation : ", obj);

obj["key4"] = "value4";

console.log("Added by bracket notation: ", obj);

console.log(obj.key1);
console.log(obj['key1']);
```

Comment: OP doesn’t want to access programmatically, they want to transform it syntactically